# Improvement of quick sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

Quick sort algorithm has bad behavior when there are many copy of items.(I mean we have Repetitive data).How could it be improved to this issue is resolved.

```
int partition (int low,int high)
{
 int j=low,i=low+1;
 int PivotItem=arr[low];
  for(int i=0,j=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    if(arr[i]==PivotItem)
     subarray[j]=arr[i];
 }
 for(i=low+1;i<=high;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]<PivotItem)
    {
        j++;
        swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
    }
}
swap(arr[low],arr[j]);
int PivotPoint=j;
return PivotPoint;
}
void quick_sort(int low,int high)
{
if(low==high)
    return ;
int PivotPoint=partition(low,high);
quick_sort(low,PivotPoint-1);
quick_sort(PivotPoint+1,high);
}
```

Comment: Are you aiming for a particular language platform? In Java `Collections.sort()` actually does merge sort especially to avoid unnecessary data copying.  In C++ you have separate `sort` (merge) and `qsort` (quick sort). Also, what do you mean by "copy of items"? If you have a list of numbers where duplicates are involved, you cannot say that they are copies. They are just duplicates who ware part of the data.

Comment: Do you mean many repeated items or items repeated many times ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I mean for example we have 11113333333222299999999000000031115553333.

Comment: Try indenting 4 blanks/level.

Comment: It could be an option to compress the data: transform the sequence to a  `(value, repeat count)` representation, Quicksort it and restore to the original representation.

Answer (score 3):

There is special modification of QuickSort known as [dutch flag sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem). It uses three-way partition for items smaller, equal and bigger than pivot  item value.

Comment: On top of this, three-way partition can be implemented with dual pivots.

Comment: @greybeard  Do you mean http://iaroslavski.narod.ru/quicksort/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf ? Definitely, that algorithm has gain for many repeated items case (but seems it doesn't solve the problem completely)

Comment: That would be the most noteworthy URL to the most cited paper. It is a fair stab at general purpose sorting with uniform access time. _Few non-repeated keys_ would seem easier than _many key repetitions_.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant the fact that quick sort compares elements based on a `<=` (or `<` and then the result is symmetrical to the next explanation) comparator, and if we look at the case where all elements are the same as the pivot `x`, you get quicksort's worst case complexity, since you split the array into two very non-even parts, one of size `n-1`, and the other is empty.

---

A quick fix to address this issue will be to use quick sort only with `<`, and `>` - to split the data to the two subarrays, and **instead of a singular pivot, hold an array that holds all the elements that equal to the pivot**, then recurse on the elements that are strictly larger than the pivot, and the elements that are strictly smaller than the pivot, and combine the three arrays.

Illustration:

```
legend: X=pivot, S = smaller than pivot, L = larger than pivot
array = |SLLLSLXLSLXSSLLXLLLSSXSSLLLSSXSSLLLXSSL|
Choose pivot - X
Create L array of only strictly smaller elements:  |SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS|
Create R array of only strictly larger elements: |LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL|
Create "pivot array" |XXXXXX|

Now, recurse on L, recurse on R, and combine:
|SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS XXXXXX LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL|
```

Comment: I put my code in my question.How to implement your solution in my code?

Comment: @sarina You need to make `partition` hold a subarray of all elements equal to the pivot (or range of elements), and when you are done, the recursion goes from `l` to the beginning of this subarray, and from the end of this subarray to `r`. Please ask what you don't understand specifically and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: I made subarray in partition function.Did you mean it? After that what i do?